# How to remove "Please enter a quantity greater than ##" when adding a product to cart

Tags: magento2, product, quantity, alert

I need to remove the `"Please enter a quantity greater than ##"` message from the product detail page, what file do I have to edit to stop only this specific alert?

Answer (score 2):

Hi Please check in your catalog product inventory for "Minimum Quantity Allowed in shopping Cart". Make sure the value is 1.